# Set up www subdomain for S3 hosted Route 53 parent domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, subdomain, amazon-route53

I have a Google Domain set up in Route 53 to point to a S3 static website (ex: 'foo.com'). It works but I'm having trouble trying to set up a subdomain (ex: 'www.foo.com') that forwards to that parent domain (basically all I want is an alias for 'www' to point to the top domain).

I've tried creating a new hosted zone for the 'www' and setting up the NS records AWS generates in there as a record in my parent zone but I only get errors when trying to access. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

In the hosed zone for `foo.com` you're going to create the `www` subdomain as a simple CNAME entry with the value being where you want it to point to.

You can follow the tutorial on how to do this in the console [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-creating.html).

Comment: I've tried this but I keep getting this error when I visit the url:
`403 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.
Bad request. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)`